# Odd Even Odd = Even Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, integers

I am trying to use algebra to prove that

`odd + even + odd = even`

so I have three numbers, where n is odd.

I know that odd + odd = even but I can't prove this idea.

$$n, n + 1, n+ 2$$

where $n$ is odd, $n+1$ is even and $n+2$ is odd.

When I add them together, I get

$$3n+3 = 3(n+1)$$

but this can't make sense because when $n = 4$, $3 \times 5 = 15$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You choose $n=4$ as even, so no wonder your example does not work.

Comment: We can simply see that we have $2$ odd numbers added together, which is an even number times an odd number, which is even. Then you are just left with even + even, which is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all an odd number there is an integer $n$, for which this number is equal to $2n-1$.

For all an even number there is an integer $n$, for which this number is equal to $2n$.

Thus, $$odd+even+odd=2n-1+2k+2m-1=2(n+k+m-1)=even.$$

Comment: best answer, just fabulous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even number: $2k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z};$

Odd number: $2k+1.$

Even + even = even:

$2k +2l =2(k+l);$

Odd +odd = even:

$(2k+1) +(2l+1) = 2[(k+l)+1]$.

Odd +even is odd:

$(2k+1) + 2l = 2(k+l)  +1.$

Even + odd ?

Answer (score 0):

write $$2k_1+1+2k_2+1+2m=2(k_1+k_2+1+m)=2m'$$ and this is even.

Answer (score 0):

In your example $n,n+1,n+2$ for $n=4$ we have the numbers $4,5,6$, where it is **not** true, that they are odd, even and odd. Indeed, the result $15$ is not even.

Answer (score 0):

When $n =4$, you're adding up $4, 5, 6$, and the total *is* 15, but that's not a problem, because you're adding up even + odd + even, not the other way around. The example you're probably thinking of is
$3 + 4 + 5$,
which is $n = 3$, and the sum is $3 \times 4$ which is 12 (an even number, as expected)

More generally, if you have

$$
odd + even + odd
$$
you can swap the last two to get
$$
odd + odd + even
$$
and now the first two sum to an even number, giving you 
$$
even + even
$$
which is always even.

Answer (score 0):

This question requires a different approach.

To ensure an odd number is produced, I use $2n-1$ or $2n+1$

To ensure an even number is produced, I use $2n$

So, now I have

$$2n-1, 2n, 2n+1$$

The sum of these numbers:

$$2n-1 + 2n + 2n+1 = 6n = 2(3n)$$

Hence as any number multiplied by 2 is even, an odd odd even combination will always be even.

Comment: It should be noted that you must use different variables for each of the numbers, as your current notation implies you're using the same exact two odd numbers, with the even number following directly afterwards.

Comment: @AleksandrH sorted.

Comment: Looks the same on my end. You need to change two of the "n"s to different variables.

Comment: @AleksandrH I have, haven't I? I now used $2n-1$ and $2n+1$

Comment: Nope. $2n-1$ and $2n+1$ are two consecutive odd numbers. For example, if $n = 3$, then $2n-1 = 5$ and $2n+1 = 7$. Furthermore, the even number in your case is sandwiched between the two odd numbers (with that example, $6$). What you're trying to prove here holds for *any* odd numbers and *any* even numbers. You need to use three different (and therefore *independent*) variables—say $x$, $y$, and $z$—to cover all possible cases.